# Why some TableLayout rows are not becoming invisible?

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

Depending on the `Spinner` selection, my replaced table should change to invisible, but if it's larger than the new table some old rows still being shown. When I select again the same option it disappears properly.

**Example CODE**

```
        Spinner s;
        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
            textSpinner = s.getSelectedItem().toString();
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    tableLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    tableLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot pinpoint the exact problem without seeing your code and layout, but using `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE` might just work:

```
switch (position){
    case 0:
        tableLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 1:
        tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tableLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
}
```